# 30 days from now skiping weekend for using MySQL INTERVAL CASE

Tags: c#, mysql, date

I am testing out an auto-billing cycle system. I have a C# script that will run every minute that checks for the next billing date but I am having an issue with the code when it is run. It returns a null date but if I change from 30 days to 14 days the scripts work like it's meant to. It is meant to run the next billing cycle from X days from the last billing day while skipping the weekend.

This part of the code works fine:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM bill_cycle WHERE DATE(NOW()) >= DATE(date_Start) AND (Next_cycle IS NULL OR Next_cycle = '' OR DATE(NOW()) >= DATE(Next_cycle)) AND status != 'suspend' AND cycle_Total != '0'";

var bill_cycle = command.ExecuteReader().ListRecordsAsDictionaries();
foreach (IDictionary<string, string> dictionary in bill_cycle)
                    {
```

It's meant to run code inside this bracket for the billing cycle to create for the client a pdf and sends an email to an email server.

This part of the code is where the issue I run in to is:

```
UPDATE bill_cycle 
SET Last_cycle=NOW(), 
    Next_cycle=(NOW() + INTERVAL CASE WEEKDAY(NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
                                     WHEN 5 THEN 30+2 
                                     WHEN 6 THEN 30+1 
                                 END DAY) 
WHERE id = 20
```

}
 Thread.Sleep(60000);
wait till timer is over and  run again.

Basically, it is not updating the clients next billing cycle of 30 days.  It is null valuing the MySQL timestamp causing it to get stuck and rerunning script over and over.

Comment: You seem to have some sort of business logic to place the next billing date on a Monday.  Can you give us some examples of this outside of the above code?  I can already think of a handful of edge cases your query may not cover.

Comment: hi sorry it seems that I was thinking PHP when looking at C# I have updated the code with added some code to help to understand what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: FYI, `Thread.Sleep(60000)` isn't timer; it's a [meme](http://starecat.com/content/wp-content/uploads/programming-function-get-tomorrows-date-sleep-getcurrentdate.jpg)